# ExtJS 5 Combobox fieldLabel binding? Why doesn't work?

Tags: extjs

I am having big troubles with data bindings in ExtJs5. I still can't understand why the field label can't be binded to the view-controller as there is a `setFieldLabel() function?`

```
{
  xtype: 'combobox',
  store: 'genderStore',
  queryMode: 'local',
  displayField: 'label',
  valueField: 'gender',
  labelAlign: 'top',
  bind:{
         value:'{scrape}',
         fieldLabel:'{myLabel}'
        }
}


formulas: {
    myLabel:function(get){
        return get('widgetSettings').properties.keyDim.dimensionName;
    },
    scrape:function(get){
        return 0;
    },
```

The value gets populated, but the fieldLabel - not.

Thanks!

Comment: What is `widgetSettings`?

Comment: A data Array in the model with some fields in it...

Comment: You can bind `fieldLabel`. The problem  might be related to your formula.

Comment: @hartonov My point was you didn't show what the value is. If it's an array, then surely it doesn't have a `properties` property?

Comment: I am sorry, it's an object :)